# How to store an Integer and its relational operator in Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have a `Measure` model with a `value` attribute who needs to be able to handle these kind of values: `1`, `0.11111`, `>=1`, `<=0.11111`, `>1`, `<1`. The logic here is that sometimes I have a discrete value and sometimes a range, depending of what is measured.

I would like to find a solution to store the values while keeping the information related to their relational operator. Also, I would prefer a solution where calculations are made at the database level instead than at the application level.

Comment: Could you tell us why you would need this functionality? Especially why you need to save an operator to your database?

Comment: What about an unbound [`numrange`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html), like `'(,0.4111)'`, `'[3,)'`, `'(,2000]'`? Not sure though RoR can easily use them.

Comment: 0.4111 is not an integer.

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and explain the problem you are trying to solve, rather than how to implement this potential solution which seems quite clunky and awkward.

Comment: I've amended my answer with a note on db searching.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new field to your measure model to store the relational type as a string (eg called 'comparison_method'), like ">=", "<" etc.  You could add validation to make sure it's in the acceptable list of comparison operators.  Store `value` as a float.

When it comes to testing, bear in mind that "<=", "<", ">=", ">", "==" and "!=" are just methods, like anything else in ruby.  There's some special syntactic sugar which allows you to say

```
2 >= 1.2
```

but this is actually equivalent to calling a method called ">=" on 2, and passing it 1.2 - like doing this, in other words:

```
2.>=(1.2)
```

Another way to call methods in ruby is to use the "send" method.  For example instead of saying

```
@user.name
```

you can say

```
@user.send("name")
```

and instead of saying

```
@user.name = "foo"
```

you can say

```
@user.send("name=", "foo")
```

So, in our case that means that we can say that

```
2.>=(1.2)
```

is equivalent to

```
2.send(">=", 1.2)
```

So, with your saved value and comparison_method, you can test these against another number like so:  let's say that @measure has value = "1.111" and comparison_method = ">=".  Let's say you have some other number @foo (equal to 2, for example) and you want to test if @foo passes the test in @measure.  You would say, for example in the controller:

```
if @foo.send(@measure.comparison_method, @measure.value)
```

which is like saying

```
if @foo >= 1.1111
```

but in a data-driven way.

You could put the above code into an instance method in Measure, like so:

```
def passes(x)
    x.send(self.comparison_method, self.value)
end
```

Now you can say, in the controller,

```
if @measure.passes(@foo)
```

which looks cleaner and is more DRY.

EDIT - incorporating the above into a database search, to do the test at the db level

```
#load a Measure, eg via params[:id]
@measure = Measure.find(params[:id])
#let's say that @measure.value = "1.111" and @measure.comparison_method = ">="
records = Foo.find(:all, :conditions => ["bar #{@measure.comparison_method} #{@measure.value}"])
#which is like saying 
#@foos = Foo.find(:all, :conditions => ["bar >= 1.111"])
```